# Codeigniter form validation return false on ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Before I start, sorry for my English. i am developing a website using **CI** on **Backend.** And i want to make a registration system without refreshing the page. If i try with post form submit i got no error and everything went good. but when I try using with `ajax request`, I can't use form validation because form validation return false and `validation_errors` is `empty`. if I disable form validation, ajax request works well. here is my controller and ajax request. Please help me.

`User.php` (**My Controller**)

```
public function register(){  
$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_kyt', 'Email', 'is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username_kyt', 'Kullanici', 'is_unique[users.username]');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data = json_encode(array('status'=> false,'info'=>validation_errors()));

    }else {

    if($this -> input -> is_ajax_request()){
          $userData = array(
            'email' => strip_tags($this->input->get('email_kyt')),
            //bla bla,
        );

        if ($this->User_model->form_insert($userData) == true) { //this method works perfectly.
            $data = json_encode(array('status' => true,'info' => 'Successfully Registered'));
        } else {
            $data = json_encode(array('status' => false,'info'=>'The Error Occurred During Registration'));
        }
    }else{
        $data = json_encode(array('status'=> false,'info'=>'This is not Ajax request'));
        }
    }
    echo $data;
}
```

}

And here is my `ajax` request in **js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn_register').on('click',function (e) {

    $('form[name=register-form]').unbind("submit"); 
            $('form[name=register-form]').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: url + 'User/register', //url is correct i tested without form validation   
                    data: $('#register-form').serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.status == true) {
                            alert(data.info);
                            window.location.reload();
                            json= [];

                        } else if (data.status == false) {
                            $('#span_validate').html(data.info);
                            json= [];
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
       });
});
```

edit: and here is my form:

```html
<!-- Register Form -->

<?php echo form_open(base_url('index.php/User/register'),array('id' => 'register-form','name' => 'register-form')); ?>
       <?php echo  form_hidden($this->security->get_csrf_token_name(), $this->security->get_csrf_hash());  ?>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" id="name_kyt" name="name_kyt" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="...">
                                <label for="name_kyt" >Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" id="surname_kyt" name="surname_kyt" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="...">
                                <label for="surname_kyt" >Surname</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="text" id="username_kyt" name="username_kyt" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="...">
                                <label for="username_kyt" > Username </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="email" id="email_kyt" name="email_kyt" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="...">
                                <label for="email_kyt" >Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="password" id="password_kyt" name="password_kyt" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="...">
                                <label for="password_kyt" >Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_onay" class="form-control">
                                <label for="password_confirm" >Password Confirm</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-3 mr-auto ml-auto">
                                        <input type="submit" name="btn_register" id="btn_register" tabindex="4" class="btn btn-register mr-auto ml-auto" value="Register">
                                        <p><span id="span_validate" class="label label-default mr-auto ml-auto"></span></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End of Register Form -->
                        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Key part of information missing here: could you show the relevant part of the HTML where the form resides? what is the exact validation error returned by form_validation?

Comment: i have edited post.. it shows no error, just empty...

Comment: If no error is being returned but the form doesn't look to be passing validation, it could mean that for some reason the post data isn't getting to your controller when going the Ajax way. You could confirm or discard this by adding the `required` rule on the controller and try submitting the form again to see what happens. If it complains about missing a required field which you are certain to have filled, we could be narrowing it down a little

Comment: I tried with just required validate but it is still return false and there is no validation errors... And if i disable form_validation, my function works well. I couldn't why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please refer below example to validate a form in CodeIgniter using ajax call.
 1. ajax code.

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn_register').on('click',function (e) {
   $('form[name=register-form]').unbind("submit"); 
        $('form[name=register-form]').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("#register-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: url + 'User/register', 
                data: formData,
                 success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == true) {
                        alert(data.info);
                        window.location.reload();
                        json= [];
                    } else if (data.status == false) {
                        $('#span_validate').html(data.info);
                        json= [];
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
  });

  2. Controller code :
  Load  form_validation library and form helper
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->helper('form');

  Now write your controller as ...
  public function register(){  
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_kyt', 'Email', 'is_unique[users.email]');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username_kyt', 'Kullanici', 'is_unique[users.username]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     echo $data = json_encode(array('status'=> false,'info'=>validation_errors())); die;

     }else {
    if($this -> input -> is_ajax_request()){
        $userData = array(
        'email' => strip_tags($this->input->get('email_kyt')),
        //bla bla,
     );

      if ($this->User_model->form_insert($userData) == true) { //this method works perfectly.
        echo $data = json_encode(array('status' => true,'info' => 'Successfully Registered')); die;
      } else {
        echo $data = json_encode(array('status' => false,'info'=>'The Error Occurred During Registration')); die;
     }
     }else{
      echo  $data = json_encode(array('status'=> false,'info'=>'This is not Ajax request')); die;
     }
   }
   }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but it is still return false :/

Comment: the is_unique validation rule works by looking for a field called username in your users database table. If the field with the same value exists it validates as false.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Form validation only works with post method. If you use get method it won't work.